# convert polygon to multi polygon

Tags: pandas, geospatial, geopandas, shapely

I have a Dataframe as below. If a FID contains more than one polygons I need to create Multipolygon for FID. In my Dataframe I have FID 978 which contains two polygons so it should be converted to Multipolygon otherwise polygon.

```
|FID|Geometry|
|975|POLYGON ((-94.2019149289999 32.171910245, -94.201889847 32.171799917, -94.2019145369999 32.1719110220001, -94.2019344619999 32.171974117, -94.2019149289999 32.171910245))
|976|POLYGON ((-94.204485668 32.175813341, -94.2045721649999 32.1758854190001, -94.2044856639999 32.1758124690001, -94.204358881 32.1757171630001, -94.204485668 32.175813341))
|978|POLYGON ((-94.30755277 32.402906479, -94.321881945 32.4028226820001, -94.321896361 32.4035500580001, -94.3074214489999 32.4037557020001, -94.3075504129999 32.4029064600001, -94.30755277 32.402906479))
|978|POLYGON ((-94.30755277 32.402906479, -94.307552779 32.4005399370001, -94.307558688 32.4005401040001, -94.30755277 32.402906479))
```

I am using the following function to convert Multipolygons

```
def ploygon_to_multipolygon(wkt):
    list_polygons =  [wkt.loads(poly) for poly in wkt]
    return shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon(list_polygons)
```

looks like polygons are not converting to Multipolygons.

Comment: I think your variable name `wkt` in the function is probably shadowing `shapely.wkt` in the outer scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from shapely.wkt import loads
from shapely.ops import unary_union

# Convert from wkt ... 
# I think there's a better way to do this with Geopandas, this is pure pandas.
df.Geometry = df.Geometry.apply(loads)

# Use groupby and unary_union to combine Polygons.
df = df.groupby('FID', as_index=False)['Geometry'].apply(unary_union)
print(df)

# Let's print out the multi-polygon to verify
print(df.iat[2,1])
```

Output:

```
   FID                                           Geometry
0  975  POLYGON ((-94.2019149289999 32.171910245, -94....
1  976  POLYGON ((-94.204485668 32.175813341, -94.2045...
2  978  (POLYGON ((-94.30755277900001 32.4005399370001...

MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.30755277900001 32.4005399370001, -94.307558688 32.4005401040001, -94.30755277 32.402906479, -94.30755277900001 32.4005399370001)), ((-94.321881945 32.4028226820001, -94.321896361 32.4035500580001, -94.3074214489999 32.4037557020001, -94.3075504129999 32.4029064600001, -94.30755277 32.402906479, -94.321881945 32.4028226820001)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your function to return the Multipolygon as wkt and to check whether there are more than one polygons in the group.

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely import wkt, geometry
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'FID': [975, 976, 978, 978],
    'Geometry': [
        'POLYGON ((-94.2019149289999 32.171910245, -94.201889847 32.171799917, -94.2019145369999 32.1719110220001, -94.2019344619999 32.171974117, -94.2019149289999 32.171910245))',
        'POLYGON ((-94.204485668 32.175813341, -94.2045721649999 32.1758854190001, -94.2044856639999 32.1758124690001, -94.204358881 32.1757171630001, -94.204485668 32.175813341))',
        'POLYGON ((-94.30755277 32.402906479, -94.321881945 32.4028226820001, -94.321896361 32.4035500580001, -94.3074214489999 32.4037557020001, -94.3075504129999 32.4029064600001, -94.30755277 32.402906479))',
        'POLYGON ((-94.30755277 32.402906479, -94.307552779 32.4005399370001, -94.307558688 32.4005401040001, -94.30755277 32.402906479))',
    ],
})
def to_multipolygon(polygons):
    return (
        geometry.MultiPolygon([wkt.loads(polygon) for polygon in polygons]).wkt
        if len(polygons) > 1        
        else polygons.iloc[0]
    )
result = df.groupby('FID')['Geometry'].apply(lambda x: to_multipolygon(x))
print(result)
```

Output

```
FID
975    POLYGON ((-94.2019149289999 32.171910245, -94....
976    POLYGON ((-94.204485668 32.175813341, -94.2045...
978    MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.30755277 32.402906479, -94...
Name: Geometry, dtype: object
```